# CORS on PHP and Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I've been working on App Engine for the past day and currently stuck on one thing.

CORS

Ive included the following to the top of my PHP files

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"');
header('Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"');
```

In my *app.yaml* file I have the following

```
application: app
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
module: default

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /ip
  script: /ip/index.php

- url: /user
  script: /user/index.php

- url: /user/auth
  script: /user/auth/index.php

- url: /user/check
  script: /user/check/index.php

- url: /user/dash
  script: /user/dash/index.php

- url: /user/forget
  script: /user/forget/index.php

- url: /user/generate
  script: /user/generate/index.php

- url: /user/link
  script: /user/link/index.php

- url: /user/maps
  script: /user/maps/index.php

- url: /user/profile
  script: /user/profile/index.php

- url: /user/register
  script: /user/register/index.php

- url: /user/reset
  script: /user/reset/index.php

- url: /user/signin
  script: /user/signin/index.php

- url: /user/signout
  script: /user/signout/index.php

- url: /user/status
  script: /user/status/index.php

- url: /user/subscription
  script: /user/subscription/index.php

- url: /user/unlink
  script: /user/unlink/index.php

- url: /user/visible
  script: /user/visible/index.php

- url: /user/alert
  script: /user/alert/index.php
```

I use the endpoints on another domain and only the first two return values, the others return something along the lines of this

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domaincom/user/status. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm unsure how to fix this issue as it only seems to be nested endpoints that fail.

Comment: I only use the first header, try removing the others. The error message indicates that it's conflicting with the 2nd header

Comment: @marcadian tried this and still the same error

Answer (score 2):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"');
```

The above fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding this to my index.php file like so:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000'); //make sure you replace 9000 by your development port
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"');
```

In the following context:

```
$app = AppFactory::create();
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();
$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"');
```

And then in my app.yaml, I added this

```
handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php
```

In the following context:

```
runtime: php74
service: packer

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php
```